# gdm Pop-Up Window on Login

Tags: rhel, login, gdm

So I was using a bit of bash script to get a popup window to appear on login for our RHEL 7 machines.  I put the following code in "/etc/gdm/PreSession/Default".

```
/usr/bin/zenity --warning --title="WARNING" --text "`cat /etc/login`" --width=80
answer=$?
if [ "$answer" == "1" ] ; then
       exit 1
fi
```

Prior to the update to RHEL 7.2 everything worked flawlessly.  Once 7.2 hit, machines hang on login.  I've tried modifying the code in various ways as well as adding it to "/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default" instead.  But either it doesn't work or login still hangs.

Is there a simple fix I'm missing?
What changed in RHEL 7.2 that causes this behaviour?
Is there an alternate method to get a window to pop-up on login?  (I've found several work-arounds, but none I'm happy with.)